# No se redimensiona la imagen que subo a la base de datos mediante mi formulario, la resolución sigue siendo la misma

Tags: php, formularios

tengo un problema con mi formularios. La imagen se sube a la base de datos con total normalidad, pero el problema es que el no se redimensiona :( el formulario esta perfecto y la conexion tambien, lo unico que no funciona es el código para redimensionar. Me gustaría que me den alguna solución o ver qué esta mal en mi código.

Holas, tengo un problema con mi formularios. La imagen se sube a la base de datos con total normalidad, pero el problema es que el no se redimensiona :( el formulario esta perfecto y la conexion tambien, lo unico que no funciona es el código para redimensionar. Me gustaría que me den alguna solución o ver qué esta mal en mi código.

Holas, tengo un problema con mi formularios. La imagen se sube a la base de datos con total normalidad, pero el problema es que el no se redimensiona :( el formulario esta perfecto y la conexion tambien, lo unico que no funciona es el código para redimensionar. Me gustaría que me den alguna solución o ver qué esta mal en mi código.

Holas, tengo un problema con mi formularios. La imagen se sube a la base de datos con total normalidad, pero el problema es que el no se redimensiona :( el formulario esta perfecto y la conexion tambien, lo unico que no funciona es el código para redimensionar. Me gustaría que me den alguna solución o ver qué esta mal en mi código.

```
**<form action="" class="formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                       <textarea name="descripcion-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" id="descripcion-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" class="descripcion-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" placeholder="¿Qué piensas?" required></textarea>


                       <div class="carga-previsualizacion-imagen">

                            No has seleccionado ninguna imagen

                       </div>

                             <style>

                                .carga-previsualizacion-imagen {
                                       font-weight: bold;
                                       display: block;
                                       background: linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(var(--color14)), rgba(var(--color11)));
                                       padding: .5vw;
                                       border-radius: .2vw;
                                       overflow: auto;
                                       max-height: 25vw;
                                       color: white;
                                       margin: auto;
                                       margin-top: .8vw;
                                       width: 42vw
                                   }

                                .carga-previsualizacion-imagen img {
                                       width: 100%;
                                       background: white;
                                       padding: 1vw
                                   }

                                .carga-previsualizacion-imagen::-webkit-scrollbar {
                                        width: .7vw;
                                        border: .45vw solid white;
                                        border-radius: 15vw;
                                        background: white;
                                    }

                                .carga-previsualizacion-imagen::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                                        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(var(--color14)), rgba(var(--color12)));
                                        border-radius: 15vw;
                                        border: .15vw solid white
                                    }

                                @media screen and (max-width: 700px){

                                    .carga-previsualizacion-imagen {
                                        max-height: none;
                                        font-size: 3vw;
                                        padding: 2vw 3vw;
                                        border-radius: 1vw;
                                        width: 89vw;
                                        margin-top: 3vw
                                    }

                                    .carga-previsualizacion-imagen img {
                                        padding: 2vw;
                                        border-radius: 1vw;
                                        width: 100%;
                                    }

                                    .carga-previsualizacion-imagen::-webkit-scrollbar {
                                            width: 2vw
                                    }

                                }

                             </style>


                       <div class="botones-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook">

                           <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="subir-imagen-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook nombre-archivo-interactivo" id="subir-imagen-label-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" name="imagen_coarbook" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected"> <!-- INPUT PARA CARGAR IMAGEN -->

                           <label for="subir-imagen-label-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" class="subir-imagen-label-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook"><div class="mostrar-nombre-archivo-interactivo">Seleccionar imagen</div></label> <!-- BOTON LABEL PERSONALIZADO-->

                           <input type="submit" class="publicar-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook" value="Publicar" name="submit_coarbook">

                       </div>

                                              <!-- |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|  EMPIEZA - INSERTACION DE DATOS A LA BASE DE DATOS (SQML)  |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|- -->

                               <?php
                               if(isset($_POST['submit_coarbook'])){

                                   $descripcionCoarbook = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlentities($_POST['descripcion-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook']));

                                   $comprobarSpam = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT descripcion FROM pub_contacto WHERE descripcion = '$descripcionCoarbook' AND id_cuenta = '".$_SESSION['id']."'"));

                                   if($comprobarSpam >= 1){

                                       echo "<div class='advertencias-formulario-registro-admin elementos-formulario-registro-admin'>Esto es spam</div>";

                                   } else {
```

/* CHECK THIS OUT *//* CHECK THIS OUT *//* CHECK THIS OUT *//* CHECK THIS OUT */

```
                                       /*IMAGEN */
                                       $resultImagenCoarbook = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE 'Name' = 'pub_coarbook'");
                                       $dataImagenCoarbook = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImagenCoarbook);
                                       $next_incrementImagenCoarbook = $dataImagenCoarbook['Auto_increment'];

                                       $randomImagenCoarbook = substr(strtoupper(md5(microtime(true))), 0, 12);
                                       $codeImagenCoarbook = $next_incrementImagenCoarbook.$randomImagenCoarbook;

                                       $extensionImagenCoarbook = 'png';
                                       $rutaImagenCoarbook = $_FILES['imagen_coarbook']['tmp_name'];
                                       $nombreImagenCoarbook = $codeImagenCoarbook.".".$extensionImagenCoarbook;



                                       $img_origen = imagecreatefrompng($rutaImagenCoarbook);
                                           $ancho_origen = imagesx($img_origen);
                                           $alto_origen = imagesy($img_origen);
                                           $ancho_limite = 700;
                                           if($ancho_origen > $alto_origen){

                                               $ancho_origen = $ancho_limite;
                                               $alto_origen = $ancho_limite*imagesy($img_origen)/imagesx($img_origen);

                                           } else {

                                               $alto_origen = $ancho_limite;
                                               $ancho_origen = $ancho_limite*imagesx($img_origen)/imagesy($img_origen);

                                           }

                                            $img_destino = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_origen, $alto_origen);

                                           imagecopyresized($img_destino, $img_origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_origen, $alto_origen, imagesx($img_origen), imagesy($img_origen));

                                           imagepng($img_destino, $rutaImagenCoarbook);



                                       if(is_uploaded_file($rutaImagenCoarbook)){

                                           $destinoImagenCoarbook = "publicaciones_img/coarbook/".$nombreImagenCoarbook;
                                           copy($rutaImagenCoarbook, $destinoImagenCoarbook);

                                       } else {

                                           $nombreImagenCoarbook = ''; 

                                       }

                                       if(comprobarNullPublicacionesCoarbook($descripcionCoarbook)){

                                           echo '<div class="advertencias-errores-generales">Asegúrese de llenar todos los campos.</div>';

                                       } else {

                                           $subirDatosCoarbook = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pub_coarbook (id_cuenta, descripcion, imagen, fecha, hora, likes, hearts, laughs, awesomes, angries, sads) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."' ,'$descripcionCoarbook', '$nombreImagenCoarbook', now(), now(), '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')");

                                           if($subirDatosCoarbook){

                                               echo "<script>location.href='HTMLCoarbook.php'</script>";

                                           } else { echo '<div class="advertencias-errores-generales">Hubo un error con el envío de la publicación.</div>'; }

                                       }

                                   }

                               }

                            ?>

                                            <!-- |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|  TERMINA - INSERTACION DE DATOS A LA BASE DE DATOS (SQML)  |-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|- -->

                    </form>**
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunos cambios en la parte PHP, ahora si escala bien la imagen, podrás poner las dimensiones que quieras, la parte modificada la comenté en el código, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_coarbook'])){

        $descripcionCoarbook = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, htmlentities($_POST['descripcion-formulario-publicaciones-coarbook']));
        $comprobarSpam = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT descripcion FROM pub_contacto WHERE descripcion = '$descripcionCoarbook' AND id_cuenta = '".$_SESSION['id']."'"));

        if($comprobarSpam >= 1){

                echo "<div class='advertencias-formulario-registro-admin elementos-formulario-registro-admin'>Esto es spam</div>";

        } else {

            /*IMAGEN */
            $resultImagenCoarbook = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE 'Name' = 'pub_coarbook'");
            $dataImagenCoarbook = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImagenCoarbook);
            $next_incrementImagenCoarbook = $dataImagenCoarbook['Auto_increment'];

            $randomImagenCoarbook = substr(strtoupper(md5(microtime(true))), 0, 12);
            $codeImagenCoarbook = $next_incrementImagenCoarbook.$randomImagenCoarbook;

            // Parte modificada

            $imagen = $_FILES['imagen_coarbook'];

            $extensionImagenCoarbook = 'png';
            $nombreImagenCoarbook = $codeImagenCoarbook.".".$extensionImagenCoarbook;

            $destinoImagenCoarbook = "publicaciones_img/coarbook/".$nombreImagenCoarbook;

            // Recoge la extensión de la imagen actual
            $extensionDeImagen = strtolower(explode('/',$imagen['type'])[1]);

            // Crea la imagen con su propio formato
            $img_origen = ('imagecreatefrom'.$extensionDeImagen)($imagen['tmp_name']);

            $ancho_origen = imagesx($img_origen);
            $alto_origen = imagesy($img_origen);

            $ancho_limite = 700;

            if($ancho_origen > $alto_origen){

                    $ancho_origen = $ancho_limite;
                    $alto_origen = $ancho_limite * $alto_origen / $ancho_origen;

            } else {

                    $alto_origen = $ancho_limite;
                    $ancho_origen = $ancho_limite * $ancho_origen / $ancho_origen;
            }

            // Escala la imagen con las dimensiones modificadas
            $imageScale = imagescale($img_origen, $ancho_origen, $alto_origen, IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED);

            // Transforma la imagen a formato png y pasa la imagen escalada al directorio indicado
            if(imagepng($imageScale, $destinoImagenCoarbook) ) {

                echo 'Se ha subido la imagen.';                 

            } else {

                    $nombreImagenCoarbook = ''; 

            }

            if(comprobarNullPublicacionesCoarbook($descripcionCoarbook)){

                    echo '<div class="advertencias-errores-generales">Asegúrese de llenar todos los campos.</div>';

            } else {

                    $subirDatosCoarbook = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO pub_coarbook (id_cuenta, descripcion, imagen, fecha, hora, likes, hearts, laughs, awesomes, angries, sads) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."' ,'$descripcionCoarbook', '$nombreImagenCoarbook', now(), now(), '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')");

                    if($subirDatosCoarbook){

                            echo "<script>location.href='HTMLCoarbook.php'</script>";

                    } else { echo '<div class="advertencias-errores-generales">Hubo un error con el envío de la publicación.</div>'; }

            }

    }

}
```